# Google label is not sharp (WKWebView)

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

When I load google page with WKWebView I have noticed that google label is not sharp. But in Safari it is good.

WKWebView
[image]

Safari
[image]

So, how can I make it sharp like in Safari ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @creeperspeak I have updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Just set customUserAgent :

```
webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.5.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15D60 Safari/604.1"
```